# How to access a row on a table based on a value from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a mini project using MySQL. I came with the following problem:

I created 2 tables, `student` and `book` with 6 and 5 columns respectively.

```
    mysql> select * from book;
+--------+------+------------+---------+------+
| bookid | Name | Authorname | edition | cost |
+--------+------+------------+---------+------+
| cc12   | dbms | guna       |       5 |  500 |
| cc34   | CA   | fasil      |       5 |  600 |
| cs113  | OS   | rohan      |       3 |  300 |
| cs12   | AI   | ganesh     |       2 | 1000 |
| cs343  | c#   | jackesh    |       4 |  300 |
+--------+------+------------+---------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from studentbook;
+-----+--------+-----------+
| Sno | bookid | Studid    |
+-----+--------+-----------+
|   1 | cc12   | 14vec1088 |
|   2 | cs113  | 14vec1099 |
|   3 | cc34   | 14vec1132 |
|   4 | cs343  | 14vec2011 |
|   5 | cs12   | 14vec100  |
+-----+--------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, when I enter any of the `studid` mentioned in the table `studentbook` (This is performed by PHP in the backend) it should display the details of book associated with the respective `studid` from the table `book`.

How can I perform the above using MySQL Query?

Comment: You need to add a WHERE clause and connect the PK with FK.

Comment: Can we see your attempt?

Comment: Can you please elaborate with a Query?

Comment: `SELECT book.Name, book.Authorname, book.edition, book.cost FROM book INNER JOIN studentbook ON studentbook.bookid = book.bookid WHERE studentbook.Studid = "14vec1088"` - same as that of Neil but an elaborated form just if you dont understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be work.

```
SELECT * FROM book
WHERE bookid IN 
(SELECT bookid FROM studentbook 
WHERE studid = "[Id of which you want book]");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you what you need.

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM book b
INNER JOIN studentbook sb on b.bookid = sb.bookid
WHERE sb.Studid = [your id]
```